# Movement script does not work (unity, C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My goal was this:
**Launching Ray> Ray found Collider> Adding this collider variable> Create Veсtor2.Lerp in which the endpoint is a transform the collider, which was found.**
The script works, but not as it should. The player does not move
(Sorry for the stupid mistakes, I'm a beginner)

```
public class move : MonoBehaviour
{
  private float speed = 150f;
  private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
  Transform EndPoint;
  private bool ready;

  void Start() { 
    rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); 
  }

  void Update() {
    MoveInfoInsert();
  } 

  void FixedUpdate() {
    Moving();
  }

  void MoveInfoInsert() { 
    if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") != 0) { 
      rb2d.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezePositionY;
      ready = true;
      if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0) {                     
        RaycastHit2D RightHit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.right * 1000f, LayerMask.GetMask("FinishForMove"));
        if(RightHit.collider != null) {
          EndPoint = RightHit.transform;
        }
      }
      else {                                                       
        RaycastHit2D LeftHit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.right * 1000f, LayerMask.GetMask("FinishForMove"));
        if(LeftHit.collider != null) {
          EndPoint = LeftHit.transform;
        }
      }
    }
    if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") != 0) {                        
      rb2d.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezePositionX;
      ready = true;
      if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") > 0) {                       
        RaycastHit2D UpHit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.up * 1000f, LayerMask.GetMask("FinishForMove"));
        if(UpHit.collider != null) {
          EndPoint = UpHit.transform;
        }
      }
      else {                                                       
        RaycastHit2D DownHit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.up * 1000f, LayerMask.GetMask("FinishForMove"));
        if(DownHit.collider != null) {
          EndPoint = DownHit.transform;
        }
      }                                                                                   
    }
  }

  void Moving() {
    if(ready == true) {
      Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, EndPoint.position, Time.fixedDeltaTime * speed);
      rb2d.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeRotation;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In general it looks like instead of `ready` you should simply set and reset (set `null`) the `EndPoint` and use `if(EndPoint)`

Comment: @derHugo, I tried what you wrote. Did not work. I also decided to try doing a "check" (in the console), and noticed that RayCast was registering colliders where it wasn't even there. Maybe it's them? Maybe I somehow misconfigured them?

Comment: I found a solution to my problem. Thanks derHugo and Armin. Firstly, it turns out that in the next argument you need to specify the length of the ray, and the direction itself did not need to be multiplied by 1000. Secondly, I had problems with the layers, which I solved. I also had a problem with the ready variable, which was not needed at all and only interfered with the work. Also there was a little problem with if

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if this is what you want to do:

```
public class move : MonoBehaviour
{

    private float speed = 150f;
    private Rigidbody2D rb2d = null;
    private Transform EndPoint = null;
    private bool ready = false;
    private LayerMask layerMask = 0;

    private void Start()
    {
        layerMask = LayerMask.NameToLayer("FinishForMove");
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        MoveInfoInsert();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Moving();
    }

    private void MoveInfoInsert()
    {
        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") != 0)
        {
            rb2d.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezePositionY;
            ready = true;
            if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0)
            {
                RaycastHit2D RightHit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.right * 1000f, layerMask);
                if (RightHit.collider != null)
                {
                    EndPoint = RightHit.transform;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                RaycastHit2D LeftHit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.right * 1000f, layerMask);
                if (LeftHit.collider != null)
                {
                    EndPoint = LeftHit.transform;
                }
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") != 0)
        {
            rb2d.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezePositionX;
            ready = true;
            if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") > 0)
            {
                RaycastHit2D UpHit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.up * 1000f, layerMask);
                if (UpHit.collider != null)
                {
                    EndPoint = UpHit.transform;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                RaycastHit2D DownHit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.up * 1000f, layerMask);
                if (DownHit.collider != null)
                {
                    EndPoint = DownHit.transform;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Moving()
    {
        if(EndPoint == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (ready == true)
        {
            transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, EndPoint.position, Time.fixedDeltaTime * speed);
            rb2d.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeRotation;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I must say that that's an unusual way to make a movement script that's using a rigidbody. what you could do instead is add forces on an axis. For example, if the player pressed a, the script would know and would add a force from the z axis. For the jump, you could have a ground check.

here are a couple movement script tutorials explaining how to make a good movement script :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwcT-Dch0bA

this video is about how to use physics to make a full 2D player movement script.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wi-RL4sUayo

this one is about different ways on how you can make a 2D player movement script, this will help you a lot, I promise!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n4N9VEA2GFo

and last but not least, this one is about how to make a 2D player movement script using the transform of the player.

There's mainly 2 ways on how to make a movement script (using physics and using the player's transform). After watching these videos, I think you will find the best way to make a movement script that fits you best.

Hope this helps a bit! :D

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. 
Link-only answers are bad! You should summarize the linked page in your answer here so your answer doesn't become 
useless in case of [link-rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).
[Why is linking bad?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/7515/174780)
| 
[Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/174780) 
| 
[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/174780)

Comment: @DavidA_ It's just that I have a game where physical properties are not applied and I thought to do it like this. (The object just moves from point A to point B and I thought Vector2.Lerp would be perfect here)

Comment: oh okay, my bad, should've made that a bit more clear in your post. But hopefully you got something out of my answer :)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi thanks for pointing that out! I am new to stack overflow so I might make mistakes like that. Did I do a slightly better job this time?